# How do I create python objects in parallel

Tags: python

I have created a class that will load a table from a csv. I need to load 6 staging tables and for doing so I am creating 6 objects by passing different parameters of the staging tables like table names, csv file names, table schemas etc.

I want to create these 6 objects in parallel in order to save time as there is no dependency.

I would like to create stg_table_load_1 to stg_table_load_6 in parallel

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    stg_table_load_1 = ChannelMinutageMedia("sampletable-1", "test_cm/sampletable-1.json", "gs://abc/test_cm/sample.csv")

    # Execute the extraction process for viewing events
    stg_table_load_1.channel_minutage_load()

    print('Exiting channel minutage load main')
```

Comment: You should probably use `multiprocessing`

Comment: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/parallel-processing-python/

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code, is it the same?

```
   stg_load_1 = ChannelMinutageMedia("mytable", "test_cm/sample_table.json",
                                          "gs://poc-data/test_cm/sample.csv")

   stg_load_2 = ChannelMinutageMedia("mytable", "test_cm/sample_table.json",
                                          "gs://poc-data/test_cm/sample.csv")
   # creating processes
   p1 = mp.Process(target=stg_load_1.channel_minutage_load())
   p2= mp.Process(target=stg_load_2.channel_minutage_load())

   # starting process 1
   p1.start()
   # starting process 2
   p2.start()

   # wait until process 1 is finished
   p1.join()
   # wait until process 2 is finished
   p2.join()
```

Comment: Yes, definitely. But I wonder why I am getting negative votes

Comment: because of your question framing style, and include thanks in advance,